Fetch request does not work with expressJS server (but both are working fine)?
I have a fetch request in a server component in a NextJS app. It looks like that (I tried to reduce all code to minimum working example) :
export async function bookRoom(params: BookingRequest) {
    const {rooms, startTime, endTime} = params;
    console.log(rooms, startTime, endTime);
    const booking = await fetch(API.bookings, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer lol`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
    });
    console.log('trying to book...', JSON.stringify(params));
    return booking.json();
}

It works fine if API.bookings is :
https://rbaskets.in/web/kkk-ttt

However when targeting http://localhost:3000/booking I receive absolutely no body (just {}).
booking.js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Register a new booking
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Check all parameters of the booking are valid
    const params = req.body;
    console.log(params);
    return res.status(201).json({'status': 'ok', 'booking': null});
});

server.js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

// Routes
const booking = require("./routes/booking");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

// bookings route
app.use('/booking', booking);


// Get the server to actually listen to a port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API server listening on port ${port} (http://localhost:${port}/)`);
});

Which is very strange to me because from Bruno (a PostMan alternative) ... everything works fine (I get {"startTime": "2024-09-02T03:23:00.000Z","endTime": "2024-09-04T03:24:00.000Z","rooms": [1]} in the console on that endpoint with the very same payload !

If any of you has a single clue !??
Note : it's important to first fire expressJS : it'll bind to port 3000 then next will fallback to 3001 if available [gonna be fixed soon : express will run on another port ...].

Tested my express endpoint with bruno ... and all was well
I started by trying to understand why my fetch was not posting the body ... with no success then to be sure :
I ran those requests against rbasket instead ... and my body was there !! So with both working independantly I'm having trouble to understand what's really going on ... Oh and since
I'm getting that {} in the expressJS console ... so I do receive the request from fetch [so I guess not really a network problem !] ! (just not the body, as it seems !!) ]

I could also mention that I have another GET endpoint on the Express server that I can fetch just fine from the NextJS (no body though, only query string)

I receive absolutely no body (just {}). - so, is it no body OR {} - there is a difference - seems your client code is sending nothing - but - you haven't shown any client code

@JaromandaX first code block is the client code

oops, sorry, missed that - so, are you receiving {} or no body? you can't receive both at the same time

@JaromandaX req.body shows only {}. I assumed it was because the body was empty

req.body being {} means it has two characters in it, { and } (i.e. what is sent from the client) - which suggests that the client is sending an empty object - what if you set body: JSON.stringify({rooms, startTime, endTime}) in your request - assuming your console.log(rooms, startTime, endTime); outputs expected values

@Phil I'm no CORS expert ... but I would not expect it to work differently between [NextJS-rbasket - Bruno-expressJS] than [NextJS-expressJS] ? Also wouldn't the request simply be blocked instead of coming with pretty much empty body ?

if it were a CORS error, the client would get a CORS error, the server would still get the request body

@Phil I'm not sure about the browser console ... since it's 2 NodeJS instances "discussing" together ... are you suggesting I'd do the request to the expressJS from a browser instead of Bruno ?

@JaromandaX Huh very good question ! I'll try right away !
Also about the {} that is the console.log output ... but since the body is preprocessed by the app.use(express.json()); middleware ... that's why I assumed it might just as well be empty and returned as {} by the middleware ! [honestly I haden't thought of your suggestion and it seemed more likely to me that there was no body at all than just an empty a body containing {} being transmitted]

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Ahh, you are right - if you send an empty body it does appear as an empty object - another thing to check ... console.log(JSON.stringify(params)) on the client

@JaromandaX Huh very good question ! I'll try right away ! Also about the {} that is the console.log output ... but since the body is preprocessed by the app.use(express.json()); middleware ... that's why I assumed it might just as well be empty and returned as {} by the middleware ! [honestly I haden't thought of your suggestion and it seemed more likely to me that there was no body at all than just an empty a body containing {} being transmitted]

@JaromandaX Well with that solution I do receive the body !
huh ... so since I couldn't make any sense of it (I console.logged the params and JSON.stringify(params) with exactly same results as {rooms, startTime, endTime}) ... I tried again with the body as JSON.stringify(params) ... and now I receive it !!!!
It is git tracked so I know for certain that it is exactly the same code as yesterday ... but now it works !
I struggled with that about 2h yesterday evening ... I restarted both instances at least 3-4 times ... And it was consistently non-working ...

So now I have no clue what's going on and am very adraid to use that in production ... I really don't want that to happen there !
Any clue on what could have caused the temporary bug ? Or maybe temporary working situation ?

Express does not parse the POST body by default. For this you need to use body parser or express's built-in express-json middleware
You can check this document

Hi, As you would know, incoming request's body parsing is based on the content-type, and in this case there is a parser loaded already - app.use(express.json()); it would be suffice for the content-type application/json which is the default one.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
